# Load specific values to Combo Box from a table

Tags: asp.net, linq

I'm stuck in a project developed by another person which I cannot understand some code blocks.
This is the code block.

```
 int outCount = 0;

                object obj = storeBO.FillStoreDDLWithLogicalQtyByItemID(cmbItem.SelectedItem.Value.CToInt(), out outCount);
            this.cmbStore.Items.Clear();

            if (outCount != 0)
            {
                support.LoadAllToComboBox(cmbStore, obj, "StoreID", "StoreName");
                lblStoreMsg.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                support.LoadAllToComboBox(cmbStore, null, null, null);
                lblStoreMsg.Text = Resources.Resource1.msgStoresNotFound;
                return;
            }
```

> cmbStore is id of Combo box

And definition of "LoadAllToComboBox" is below.

```
public void LoadAllToComboBox(AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox cmb, object dataSource, string dataValueField, string dataTextField)
        {
            try
            {
                cmb.Items.Clear();
                cmb.SelectedValue = null;

                cmb.DataSource = dataSource;
                cmb.DataValueField = dataValueField;
                cmb.DataTextField = dataTextField;
                cmb.DataBind();
                cmb.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select", "Select"));
                cmb.SelectedValue = "Select";



            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                throw exception;
            }

        }
```

Please someone help me to understand this two code blocks. It will be great, if someone can explain these two code blocks to me.

Specially, I want to know this DataBind is binding to where.(through which one I can reach the LINQ code)

Comment: There is no LINQ query in your code. The question is unclear

Answer (score 1):

Its easy to understand here ...

1. LoadAllToComboBox is common function in you application which allows to load value to comobo boxes in your application
2. DataBind() method in asp.net used to bind server control with the datasoruce which is in your code "dataSource"
3. there is no linq used in this code it just normal binding used

I suggest you google out DataBinding in Asp.net Application, you will get answer

Comment: _"Specially, I want to know this DataBind is binding to where... through which one I can reach the LINQ code"_ I guess he wants to modify the query somehow which is passed as `System.Object` and came from `FillStoreDDLWithLogicalQtyByItemID`. The question is pretty unclear

Comment: @TimSchmelter - ok , i though he want to know how code works ..so provided information about it...and there is no linq...it just normal databinding in asp.net with datasource object

Comment: I needed to know, how the code works ! I got some idea from your answer. You mean that, there are no any linq connected with this "dataSource" from behind ? Because I want to modify this code to get stores to this Combo box, which are items available. (If there are no any item in a store, that store should not load to Combo box.

Comment: @MohanPerera - i dont see there is any linq used in code ...your datasource is coming from here bject obj = storeBO.FillStoreDDLWithLogicalQtyByItemID